# How to detect browser back click in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Anyone please resolve my problem. I need to write If condition for browser back button. I have tried so many ways but it not giving the exact result.

```
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
}
```

In the above code `window.performance.navigation.type` is always returning the value 1.

And also tried `ngOnDestroy()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with `HostListener`

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back button clicked');
}
```

Comment: use in app.component.ts

Comment: `HostListener` is working but i want to check whether someone is clicks the back button or refresh the page.

Comment: for refresh hostListener is 

@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
      console.log("refresh");
  }

Comment: we need to check whether the page is loaded due to refresh or user came that page by clicking the back Button.

Comment: Did you understand what i m saying?